# ng-show in angular give mistake

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-show

Why this code give error? I get error that "Cannot set property 'show' of undefined"

```
<div ng-controller='DeathrayMenuController'>
<button ng-click='toggleMenu()'>Toggle Menu</button>
<ul ng-show='menuState.show'>
<li ng-click='stun()'>Stun</li>
<li ng-click='disintegrate()'>Disintegrate</li>
<li ng-click='erase()'>Erase from history</li>
</ul>
<div/>

function DeathrayMenuController($scope) {
$scope.menuState.show = false;
$scope.toggleMenu = function() {
$scope.menuState.show = !$scope.menuState.show;
};
// death ray functions left as exercise to reader
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the `show` property on `$scope.menustate` if `$scope.menustate` is `undefined`. You need to initialize it first:

```
$scope.menuState = {};
$scope.menuState.show = false;
```

or alternatively:

```
$scope.menuState = {
    show: false
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you are going to assign a `show` property to `$scope.menuState` object but you don't have `$scope.menuState` object,

so what u need to do is, create a `$scope.menuState` object beginning of the controller as,

```
function DeathrayMenuController($scope) {
   $scope.menuState = {};           // initialize the object first.
   $scope.menuState.show = false;
   $scope.toggleMenu = function() {
       $scope.menuState.show = !$scope.menuState.show;
   };
   // death ray functions left as exercise to reader
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining $scope.menuStage first. Try this instead:

```
<div ng-controller='DeathrayMenuController'>
<button ng-click='toggleMenu()'>Toggle Menu</button>
<ul ng-show='menuState_show'>
<li ng-click='stun()'>Stun</li>
<li ng-click='disintegrate()'>Disintegrate</li>
<li ng-click='erase()'>Erase from history</li>
</ul>
<div/>

function DeathrayMenuController($scope) {
$scope.menuState_show = false;
$scope.toggleMenu = function() {
$scope.menuState_show = !$scope.menuState_show;
};
// death ray functions left as exercise to reader
}
```